# Team Development Strategy for Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-4

Our developers must first develop the application on their local and then version to dev environment for testing as a version.

I have currently two ideas.

1) Every developer installs to his own computer a glassfish server. When the change is ready, the deployment is done to the glassfish dev server.

2) Every developer has a domain on glassfish dev server. And there is one more domain which acts as a dev server. When the change is ready, deployment is done to the dev server domain.

I'd like to try my second idea ( one domain for each developer in same glassfish installation ). Is it possible ? What is the best practice for that ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the resources you have.

If you have good-enough development machines, it is worth to install a local Glassfish environment. If you intend to use JRebel, for example, it is the best choice.

If the dev machines are not so good, or you have resources that are only accessible centrally (e.g. through a firewall, by IP), the central solution is better.

I have already worked with both setups, I think it is better to have the environment locally. You have more control over the processes, easier to deploy, not suffering from the central server bottlenecks (low memory, CPU).